# Do certain buddy missions in Far Cry 2 lock out other ones?

Tags: far-cry-2

I've been playing Far Cry 2 on Infamous (hardest) difficulty. (It really gives you an appreciation for tactics.)  I've kept all my buddies alive, Flora is my best buddy and Warren is my rescue buddy.  I've also saved Quarbani and Michele, and they're currently chilling in Mike's Bar.

They both offered me a mission at the same time - I ignored Michele to do Quarbani's mission because it seemed quicker, with the idea that I'd come back and do Michele's afterwards.

But after I returned to Mike's and reported in to Quarbani, Michele no longer offered that mission.

**Did I miss it forever, or will she offer it again later?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just discovered that the answer is **yes, she will offer it again later.**

Comment: You actually just need to get a certain distance away from Mike's, so that the area 'reloads'. Drive up to the creek with the split path with the ramp (as if you're heading to Pala) and check your map. Mike's should show another mission available.